# Update WordPress user ID with CAS server ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cas

I've setup a WordPress site and the authentication is done with a CAS server.
I am using the WP Cassify plugin to connect with the CAS server.

Is it possible to update the wp_users ID from the default one, to the ID my server returns? If so, should i update with the new ID the wp_usermeta?
Or should i create an extra column in the wp_users table?
Are there any other tables that need to be updated?

The CAS server returns a string e.g."0A2B4C6D8EABCDEF1234567" which i want to use as ID for other services connected to my site.

Comment: you may need to keep this as separate meta, as WP will not allow to create a user with specific ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, as suggested in comment above, would be to implement it in the user meta - as the ID is the user table's primary key, so can't be changed.

Add this line of code to save the CAS ID after the user is registered via WordPress:

`update_user_meta( $wordpress_user_id, 'cas_id', $cas_id_value );`

And then if you need to retrieve it afterwards touse:

`$cas_id = get_user_meta( $wordpress_user_id, 'cas_id' );`